# Early access to Salesforce1 app for iOS

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform, pre-release

We got an email from Salesforce saying that Salesforce1 v12.0 app for iOS is about to release in mid Feb 2017 which has new `WKWebView` which is replacing old `UIWebView`, which will enhance performance and all.

My question is, Is there any way to get pre-release version of Salesforce1 app for iOS for testing like "Salesforce1 for Android Early Access Community" which gives notifications related to Salesforce1 app pre-release version for android and gives apk to test it before it's actually available to customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sign up for the TestFlight beta version here: 
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeodqK9rFv_rU1QHnnhfMB-XaWKvQcnrLWOo3j-xCb2lWinbw/viewform

Comment: Thank you @Dan.. I have submitted the form. Lets see how it goes. Thank you once again.